# Having trouble to startactivity inside a new thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity

I am trying to start a background activity. so I have the following

```
           new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            this.startActivity( new Intent(this, WhereAmI.class));
        }
    }.start();
```

The problem with that is startActivity cannot be created within the new thread. If this cannot be done, how I can start the new activity in background so it won't affect the current GUI.

Answer (score 2):

Look up Android [Services](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html).  Those are the "background" activities that do not affect the current UI.  Please note that services are not threads and do run on the main UI thread.  Also, you can not start a service in a thread.  If there's any blocking activities that needs to be done, you must start a thread inside the `Service` itself.